# Google Tink Key management and sharing from android to .NET to decrypt data to server end which is encrypted at mobile(client) end

Tags: android, .net, encryption, key-management, tink

I am trying to make an end to end encrypted app where I encrypt data at the mobile end at the time of sending and we can decrypt it at the server(for user info). but I am not able to find any solution or example for how we can manage or share key which is generated at the mobile end for encrypting data to decrypt at server(.NET) end.

#Googel_Tink

Comment: My understanding of encryption is very basic but, if it's used for decryption, I don't think you can safely transfer the key for your server to use without already having private communication set up. Have you considered generating a public-private key pair for your server and having your server share the public key with the mobile end?

Comment: No, I haven't known about it can you give me an example  how to use public-private key pair in tink?

Comment: I've not implemented such a system myself. But I would suggest looking into the Hybrid Encryption sections in Tink's how-to guides.